# MVC4 Isn't a good practice to handle session or query string in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I just started working on `MVC`, this is what I written inside a `cshtml` page

```
@if (Request.QueryString["TechID"] != null)
{
int TechID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["TechID"].ToString());
forumAPP.newForumDBEntities db = new forumAPP.newForumDBEntities();
var topic = from p in db.tblTechnologies where p.TechID == TechID select p.TechName;
string strText = "A forum where you can post questions regarding " + topic.FirstOrDefault().ToString(); ;
@Html.Label("Name", strText)
}
```

I just want to know whether it is a good practice or not to write some code like handling sessions to display some sample content like `Username` or desired text instead of writing in a `model`

Comment: bad practice to make db calls in View. Violates Separation of Concerns.

Comment: `Dave A` thanks is it possible to bind label using `url.action`

Comment: You wouldn't want to mix the 2. The most important principle is to keep Views as passive as possible. Do as much of the processing outside the view. Ideally in Controller (and some would say in the Model).

Comment: Ok how can I write a method to bind a label dynamically

Comment: please explain dynamically. In principle, if you send a populated model to the View, you can use a displayfor(m=>m.{property}) to display any value you passed. When I think dynamically, I think something that happens after the view is rendered (like a selection from dropdown). But that becomes a more complex subject involving Ajax.